# property is not declared configurable (Error: <spyOnProperty>)

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

Given a `MenuComponent`

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'cg-menu',
  templateUrl: './menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './menu.component.scss' ]
})
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {
  menu: MenuItem[];

  isLoggedIn$ = this.authStateService.isLoggedIn.pipe(untilDestroyed(this));

  constructor(private readonly authStateService: AuthStateService,
              private readonly router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authStateService
      .state
      .pipe(
        untilDestroyed(this),
        ...some logic...
      .subscribe();
  }

  ...some logic...
}
```

and a `AuthStateService`

```js
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthStateService {
  private readonly state$: Observable<AuthState | null>;
  private readonly isLoggedIn$: Observable<boolean | null>;

  constructor(private readonly sessionManager: SessionManagerService) {

    this.state$ = this.stateTrigger$
      .pipe(
        ...some logic...
        shareReplay(1));

    this.isLoggedIn$ = this.stateTrigger$
      .pipe(
        map(state => state !== null),
        shareReplay(1));
  }

  get state(): Observable<AuthState> {
    return this.state$;
  }

  get isLoggedIn(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.isLoggedIn$;
  }

  ...some logic...
}
```

When I'm trying to run this code, Karma is triggering an error.

```js
describe('MenuComponent', () => {
  let component: MenuComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MenuComponent>;

  let authStateServiceSpy;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    authStateServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj(
      'AuthStateService',
      {},
      {
        state: of(null),
        isLoggedIn: of(false)
      });

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ MenuComponent ],
      imports: [ RouterTestingModule ],
      providers: [
        { provide: AuthStateService, useValue: authStateServiceSpy }
      ],
      schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MenuComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should generate correct menu (expert)', () => {
    // The problem is here
    spyOnProperty(authStateServiceSpy, 'state', 'get').and.callFake(() => of(stateMock));

    expect(component.menu).toEqual([
      ...something...
    ]);
  });
});
```

The error is this.

```sh
Error: <spyOnProperty> : state is not declared configurable
    Usage: spyOnProperty(<object>, <propName>, [accessType])
    Error: <spyOnProperty> : state is not declared configurable
    Usage: spyOnProperty(<object>, <propName>, [accessType])
        at <Jasmine>
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/src/app/modules/structure/components/menu/menu.component.spec.ts:55:5)
        at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:364:1)
        at ProxyZoneSpec.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:292:1)
        at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:363:1)
        at Zone.run (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:123:1)
        at runInTestZone (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:545:1)
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:560:1)
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score -2):

<strike>I guess it's because `AuthStateService`'s `state` is a *getter* in the class, but **your mock** declares it as regular property. You should declare it as *getter* as well.</strike>

The issue seems related to using `createSpyObj` in conjunction with `spyOnProperty`, since it's not a *real getter* you're trying to spy on.

Looking at your code, there seems to be no reason to use `createSpyObj` though, so this might do the trick:

```js
    // ... 

    authStateServiceMock = {
        get state() { return of(null) },
        get isLoggedIn() { return of(false) },
    };

    // ...

    spyOnProperty(authStateServiceMock, 'state', 'get').and.callFake(() => of(stateMock));
    
    expect(component.menu).toEqual([
        ...something...
    ]);
```

Comment: any idea how to do that? I tried many things, but no of them it's working.

Comment: still not working. like this is not triggering any errors but it's not changing the state at all.

Comment: @simonepachera I guess your `component.menu` gets initialized before the getter is accessed (e.g. during component initialization). The mock need's to be setup before that to work.

Comment: Won't work. Still getting `Error: <spyOnProperty> : <functionName> is not declared configurable`.